# Parser error while running application

Tags: c#

`Could not load file or assembly 'ScriptReferenceProfiler' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I get this error after running the application. What is the likely issue?
I am using visual studio 2008, .NET 3.5 sp1 for C#.

*ASP.NET application debugging after the build.

** Assembly load trace

`=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ORG-FA431C61BE1\ahsan
LOG: DisplayName = ScriptReferenceProfiler
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/myproj/myproj/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\myproj\myproj\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).`

`LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\myproj\myproj\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS.0\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.`

Comment: You will need to provide more information than this to get an answer.  It's *extremely* vague.

Comment: The references might not be added for ScriptReferenceProfiler. Check them. If running means executing the exe, the file must already be there. If you are just copying the exe, copy the dll's as well

Comment: This is when i debug after a successful build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause is that the `ScriptReferenceProfiler` assembly that your application depends upon has not been referenced or an incorrect version of it has been referenced. Once you reference the assembly and compile the project, Visual Studio will automatically copy it to the output folder so that it can be resolved at runtime. If this is an ASP.NET application the assembly has to be present in the `bin` folder. Otherwise it should be along with the executable.

Comment: It is there as a REFRESH file.

Comment: @gandalfish, a REFRESH file contains only the path, but the actual assembly needs to be copied at the `bin` folder. Normally this should be done by Visual Studio when you compile. If, when you run the site, the assembly itself is not present in the bin folder it won't work. Verify that the REFRESH file points to the correct location of the assembly. Try removing and adding the reference once again.